# Initial value problem for $y' = \alpha y - y^2$ with $y(0)=y_0 \neq 0$ and $\alpha > 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm solving past exam questions in preparation for an Applied Mathematics course. I came to the following question. *If it's any indication of difficulty, the exercise is only Part 1-A of the sheet so it's supposed to be pretty easy*

> Solve the initial value problem $y' = \alpha y - y^2$ with $y(0)=y_0 \neq 0$ and $\alpha > 0$

The problem is, I can't seem to be able to deal with that $y^2$, as in my methodology I am urged to integrate over $\frac{dy}{dt}$, and the square ruins that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Hints:** Separation of Variables and Complete the Square.

Comment: @Moo tried that before, ended up at $y' + (y+\frac{\alpha}{2})^2 =\frac{\alpha^2}{4}$, is this form helpful somehow?

Comment: Yes, and the answers show how.

Comment: look up logistic differential equation. the solution is $y = \frac 1{\alpha(1+ce^{-\alpha t})}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = ay -y^2 \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{ay -y^2} = dt$$

$$\int_{y(0)}^{y(t)}\frac{dy}{ay -y^2} = \int_0^t dt \Rightarrow \\
\int_{y(0)}^{y(t)}\left[\frac{1}{ay} - \frac{1}{a(y-a)}\right]dy = t \Rightarrow \\
\frac{1}{a}[\log(y(t)) - \log(y(0))] - \frac{1}{a}[\log(y(t)-a) - \log(y(0)-a)] = t \Rightarrow \\
\log\left(\frac{y(t)(y(0)-a)}{y(0)(y(t)-a)}\right) = at \Rightarrow \\
\frac{y(t)}{y(t)-a} = e^{at}\frac{y(0)}{y(0)-a} \Rightarrow \\
y(t)\left[1-e^{at}\frac{y(0)}{y(0)-a}\right] = -ae^{at}\frac{y(0)}{y(0)-a} \Rightarrow
y(t) = \frac{-ae^{at}y(0)}{y(0)-a-e^{at}y(0)}.$$

Comment: I sincerely thank you for this. Any explanation on how you went from $\frac{1}{ay-y^2}$ to $\frac{1}{ay} - \frac{1}{a(y-a)}$?

Answer (score 0):

$$y'=\alpha y-y^2$$
$$y'-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}=\alpha y-y^2-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}=-(y-\frac{\alpha}{2})^2$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{\frac{\alpha^2}{4}-(y-\frac{\alpha}{2})^2}=\int dx$$
which can then be solved.